# Jquery slide menu going in wrong direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there way to change the direction of the slide from right to left when clicking on "main menu link" only. Direction of slide is good for all other links (target 1, target 2, target 3). 
http://jsfiddle.net/L7v0w96s/26/

```
jQuery(function($) {

$('a.panel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.animate({
                left: $this.innerWidth()
            }, 500, function() {
                $this.removeClass('active')
            });
        });

        $target.css({
            left: -($target.innerWidth())
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500).addClass('active');
    }
});

});
```

UPDATE: Here is a new new fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/L7v0w96s/33/ I have the slide direction correct now. I still need to work on the timing of the slides, but at least I have the direction correct. This is the best I can do for now.

Comment: What have you tried? Obviously you'll need to differentiate for that one link.

Comment: We can just add "main" to the class of that link.

Comment: I have been trying different things for a long time with no success. I'm a newbie, so most of the stuff has been css changes.

Comment: So show us. It's a basic minimum requirement at SO that you show your code.

Comment: The changes I make are in the fiddle and I don't save them if they don't work.

Comment: All I have is the code provided by the fiddle link. It shows all the html, jquery and css.

Comment: From the updated jsfiddle, it seems like you fixed the problem. Answer your question below and then mark it as the correct answer.